# Airflow: How to take out a task that is now not included in DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have this problem. I changed the DAG workflow to replace on task with another. But it seems that the replaced task is still reflecting but is not part of the workflow already (please see image). My question is, how to take out that task?

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to turn off the DAG, restart the scheduler (or just start it with `airflow scheduler`) and **wait**. Usually the changes in the DAGs are only picked up after a while that the scheduler is running.

Also it could happen that while refreshing either the graph view or tree view of the DAG you'll see the task "randomly" appear and disappear, until it finally stabilize at the latest version.

After some scheduler cycles have passed and after refreshing you only see the new configuration, you can safely turn the DAG back on.

Comment: Will take note of restarting the scheduler. Did it once though and still nothing happened. Regarding the "random" behavior you speak of, it's not happening in this case. Will upvote your answer. :)